# Use jQuery to make a "column" on the default view?

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, list-view, view

I am trying to append a value to the end of each row by selecting the number value in one column to do some sort of math with it and output the value on the other one. This code works for me on one site, but it doesn't work on another site (appending the "Fake Column" part is the only one that works on the second site). I'm not sure what the difference is since they have the same IDs. Is there an issue with it or is it the site?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#onetidDoclibViewTbl0 tr:first').append("<td>Fake Column</td>");
   $('#onetidDoclibViewTb0 tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
//this only works to select the value in my first site, but I'm also not sure how to select the column without referring to its exact order (24th)
     var someDate = new Date($(this).find('td:nth-child(24)').text());
     var today = new Date();
     if(someDate > today) {

//this works on the first site to append some number after on the first site
//and highlight all the rows, but it doesn't work on the second site. 
         $(this).append("<td>"+ "SomeValue" + "</td>");
         $(this).css('background-color','#F8FC8F');

     }
   });
});
```

Any suggestions?

edit: my reasoning for not using a calculated column or workflow is due to restrictions with using the "today" date dynamically :/

Comment: Is ajax interfering? For instance if the view has grouping enabled it will load through ajax. Many other scenarios can result in ajax as well, such as enabling asynchronous loading on the XsltListViewWebPart. - if yes than your selector will most likely fail, or the resulting text is initially wrong

Comment: I don't use grouping, but this page does have a lot more code modification going on in the background. How would I check to see if ajax is failing? If it is, am I simply out of luck?

Comment: Ajax does not have to fail, it just means that the DOM is populated _after_ your code tries to work on it. There are several ways to test this, like a simple `console.log` of your selector result, or a `debugger` statement for the same purpose, e.g., `console.log($('#onetidDoclibViewTbl0 tr:first').length)`. Other ways is to keep an eye on the network transfers, to see if the content is actually loaded through XHR